# Yarn - Use global binary instead of local binary

Tags: zsh, yarnpkg

I have a binary named "now" that is installed both locally and globally.

The local version uses now@17, while the global version uses now@16.

I want to keep my local version as-it.

I want to invoke the global version from the directory where the local version is installed.

But if I run `yarn now` it'll run the local version. Using `yarn global now` returns invalid subcommand.

Is there an easy way to do that? I feel like the easiest way is to manually add that specific binary under another alias in my `.zshrc` file.

Comment: You might want to consider adding zsh as a tag to this post.

Comment: I updated. Not sure if it's so useful as I don't believe it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yarn global bin` to prefix the command.

```
$(yarn global bin)/now
```

Comment: `$(yarn global bin)/now --version` worked like a charm and displayed `16.7.3`. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, using `now` would use the global installed package and using `npx now` would use the local one, it's even simpler. I thought it would use the local when running `now` but I was wrong.